# Python: Find item in multidimensional list

Tags: python, list, find, multidimensional-array

I have a list of lists, a snippet of which is below:

`x_attrib = []`

```
self.x_attrib.append(["Is_virtual", False, 'virtual', 'flag'])
self.x_attrib.append(["X_pos", None, 'pos/x', 'attrib'])
self.x_attrib.append(["Y_pos", None, 'pos/y', 'attrib'])
```

I want make a functional that returns the index of the item at the first position (i.e. I want to pass `"X_pos"` to a function, and have it return `1`).

How can I do this?

Comment: what have you tried? (You are more likely to get help if you show evidence of having tried and failed then if you just ask for a soluation)

Comment: Heh, I don't know how to start. I am trying to find an item in the list inside the list, then return the outer list. I guess I could write an iterating function, but it would be grossly inefficient. I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, you need to something like this:

```
def find_it(key):
   for index, sublist in enumerate(lists):
       if sublist[0] == key:
            return index
```

Having said that your code looks like you are solving the more general problem incorrectly. i.e. that list look like a bad idea. Without a better idea of what you are doing I cannot be certain.

Comment: I am parsing xml, and storing the values, x_paths, etc in the list. I am doing this to avoid repeating code, since I have several different types of files to parse. Yeah, its ugly, but I can't think of a better way.

Comment: I entered that code (changed lists-->x_attrib), but it says improper syntax on the 2nd line.

Comment: After your code works, you can post it on codereview.stackexchange.com, and I'll probably tell you how to do it without being ugly.

Comment: @Blosci3c, that was a test to see if you understood what I wrote. Just kidding, missing colon on the second line.